# Read emails sents using java

Tags: java, linux

I want to write a Java program that reads emails contents that user sent over the internet in Linux. 
So, I wonder if there is a way to access browser's history and read emails' contents.
Also, I want to detect if he/she sent an email using mail command, and access the email content.

My purpose is to detect if the user copied some data, and sent it outside the organization.
Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: While the question itself is too broad for Stack Overflow, consider this:  you shouldn't need to go through the browser to accomplish any of this.  There have been standalone mail clients for decades.  Read up on POP3 and IMAP, as those are good places to start.

Comment: @Makoto The OP apparently doesn't want to write a mail client; he wants to write spyware.

Answer (score 0):

Lets ignore your desire to do this in Java, and focus on whether it is possible *in theory* ... in any language.

> So, I wonder if there is a way to access browser's history and read emails' contents.

That is probably impossible.  The user's browser history won't contain the email contents, and probably won't contain the metadata either.

> Also, I want to detect if he/she sent an email using mail command, and access the email content.

A privileged program can query what programs have been executed (locally) ... provided that the Linux system is configured with "system accounting" enabled.  (It generally isn't by default!)

However, that would only tell you that `mail` was executed, and possibly the command line arguments.  It won't give you the email content.

---

There are possibly other ways to get the email content, such as snooping the network traffic at the instant that the email is being sent.  However, there is a good chance that the network traffic will be (strongly) encrypted at that point.

And so on.

In short, there is no easy way to get all of a user's email conversations ... unless you can *force* him / her to send all of their email via a relay that you control.

(IMO, this is a good thing!  It is unethical to read other people's email without their knowledge, even if you are their boss.  And besides, given the easy availability of mobile devices, a tech-savvy user can easily evade your snooping.)

Comment: I want to read the email only if they copy something from my data to know if they sent it outside the organization.

Comment: @Dareen - That doesn't change the morality of what you propose to do ... unless you are the boss, and you have made it clear to everyone that it is a condition of their employment that you have their agreement to snoop on their email.  (And irrespective of that, they may have **legal** protection, under your state or country's employment or privacy laws.)

Comment: @Dareen - Or to put it another way, if you were my boss, and you were snooping on my email like this, I would be tempted to resign on the spot.

Comment: I'm still thinking in a way to protect my data. I wont do something illegal. My idea is when I detect a user copied something from the organization system, I search his/her emails to check if s/he sent data outside the organization. I'm not planning to search all users emails. If there is a way to that at the same time of coping data, it would better.

Comment: @Dareen - I can't help you.  And I don't want to, because I think what you are proposing to do is immoral.  (And whether you agree with that is immaterial.)

Comment: @Dareen It's thoroughly impractical to detect "copying something"; that's the whole point of what computers do. And if you're really in the legitimate scenario you describe, it's feasible to set up firewall rules that require outgoing mail to run through a company e-mail server that can scan for sensitive information.

Comment: @chrylis - He also needs to block access to webmail sites.  And, to be sure, he also needs to ban users from bringing smartphones, memory sticks, etc into the office.  Only a total idiot would use interceptable / snoopable email to deliberately steal "valuable" information.  Not withstanding the morality issue, his whole approach is probably futile.

Comment: @StephenC If you're blocking Webmail, then bring on the file lockers!